# Неправильно обрабатывается массив

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, циклы

**System.IndexOutOfRangeException не обработано

Message=Индекс находился вне границ массива.**
Код:

```
public string[] array = { };
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    array[i] = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Массив пуст. Тут перебирать надо по array. Т.е. условие выхода — i < array.Lenght

```
public string[] array = new string[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Lenght ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i.ToString();
    }
```

Дополнение:

```
public List<string> links = new List<string>(100);
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  links.Add(line);
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: Пример можешь дать?

Comment: Обновил. Вот так добъешься инициализации от "0" до "4" в строковом массиве.

Comment: У меня не дано сколько элементов должно быть в массиве.
Следует List<string> юзать?

Comment: А цель какая у твоей задачи?

Comment: В цикле пропарсить кол-во ссылок.
А этих ссылок там штук 100, точно не знаю. 
И добавить их в массив

Comment: Если размер коллекции заранее не известен — то да, юзай любой из generic-типов. Если счет идет на тысячи, лучше используй Queue<T> или Stak<T>. Если немного — то List<T>. Откуда ссылки берешь? Из файла? Я обновил пример. Смотри дополнение.

Comment: Да, беру из файла
        public List<string> array = new List<string>();  
            array.Add("test");
            array[1] = "test1"; Тут ошибку пишет

Comment: Я выше привел реализацию. Это по поводу чтения из файла. Ошибку пишет потому что массив начинается с 0 элемента. Т.е. array.Add("test"); добавляет 0 элемент. array[1] = "test1"; дает исключение, т.е. 1 индекса еще нет. Можно добавить array.Add("test1"); и ты получишь массив из 2 элементов. Или присвоить уже существующим индексам новые значения. array[0] = "test1"; заменит test на test1

Comment: Все, окей спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в массиве похоже только 1 элемент, а ты пытаешься пройти по 5 элементам. Если хочешь динамический массив, то используй List. Размер массива задается 1 раз при объявлении.

Comment: А у меня не дано сколько элементов должно быть в массиве.